# WPF Magellan: is there a way to navigate to a existing view?

Tags: wpf, navigation, magellan

I'm using the excellent [Magellan navigation framework](http://www.paulstovell.com/magellan) from [Paul Stovell](http://www.paulstovell.com/).

When you have this method in the controller

```
Public Function Save(ByVal Contact As Contact) As ActionResult
    Try
        Contact.Save()
        Return Index() ''//Call other action result that brings the list of contacts
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return New CancelResult
    End Try
End Function
```

1. Is there a way that `Index` does not create another view, but navigate to the existing one (if exists)?
2. Is there a way to destroy a View (in this case, the contact view, which is not longer valid because the record is already saved in the DB)

Comment: Hi Eduardo, what kinds of views are you using? Are they Windows or pages? By reusing the view, do you mean to re-focus on the view? Let me know and I'll show how a ViewEngine can be used to achieve this.

Comment: I'm using pages and yes, re-focus in the view (going back or forward in the navigation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be able to accomplish this using the Action and Result Filters feature:

http://www.paulstovell.com/magellan-action-and-view-filters

You could use OnResultExecuted to track the page that was rendered. Then you could handle OnResultExecuting to see the target page - if it's a page that exists in the navigation journal, you could issue GoBack/GoForward commands to navigate back to the page.